# How to send rows to error output in an SSIS Pivot transformation?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS project in VS 2013 with a Pivot task. It gives the red Pivot Error Output arrow for you to use, but when I use it, it gives a warning on the Pivot task saying "No rows will be sent to error output(s). Configure error or truncation dispositions to redirect rows".  Is there a setting somewhere to redirect the rows? I've looked through the advanced editor and task properties. I believe (based on a project where this does work) that the "Configure Error Output" window is supposed to pop up when you connect the error path, but this is not showing for me.  Instead I get the error in the second screen shot. I have set up my input, output, and error columns.

[image: Warning on Pivot task]

[image: error window]

[image: advanced editor]

Comment: This might be a bug in Visual Studio 2012/2013. Going to see if it will work in 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a bug, a workaround was found by editing the .dtsx file in a text editor.  Find the Pivot task, and then find the inputColumn tag for the column you used as the pivot key, and below the cachedName property, add a new property- errorRowDisposition="RedirectRow".  Then save and reopen in Visual studio and the warning should be gone.